# Texstudio cwl specialDef

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

In the Background information for Texstudio
(https://texstudio-org.github.io/background.html#description-of-the-cwl-format)
for the cwl format, there is mentionend "special lists" whith the following example given:

```
\definecolor{name%specialDef}{model}{color-spec}#s#%color
\color{color%special}
```

what are those special lists supposed to do? Should all names defined by \definecolor be stored in the list %color and then be suggested when \color{} is typed? currently i'm not getting this to work. Does anyone have more information about this?

Thank you!